# Unable to search effectively in Emacs

Tags: search, emacs

I want to have a similar tool in Emacs as the following in Vim

```
 :g/search/
```

to get a list of matches.

**How can you get a list of matches in Emacs?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`M-x occur`?

From [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html):

> `M-x occur`
>
> Prompt for a regexp, and display a list showing each line in the buffer that contains a match for it. The text that matched is highlighted using the `match` face. To limit the search to part of the buffer, narrow to that part (see Narrowing). A numeric argument `n` specifies that `n` lines of context are to be displayed before and after each matching line. The default number of context lines is specified by the variable `list-matching-lines-default-context-lines`.
>
> In the `*Occur*` buffer, you can click on each entry, or move point there and type `RET`, to visit the corresponding position in the buffer that was searched. `o` and `C-o` display the match in another window; `C-o` does not select it. Alternatively, you can use the `` C-x ` ``  (`next-error`) command to visit the occurrences one by one (see Compilation Mode).
>
> Typing `e` in the `*Occur*` buffer switches to Occur Edit mode, in which edits made to the entries are also applied to the text in the originating buffer. Type `C-c C-c` to return to Occur mode.
>
> The command `M-x list-matching-lines` is a synonym for `M-x occur`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `M-x occurr` check also M-x grep. This works in several files at once.

Comment: `rgrep` is even better as it allows recursive search.

Answer (score 4):

My usual workflow is not to get a list and choose (don't know how to do that), but to use the incremental search:

```
C-s <search target>
```

gets the fist match after the point. If you don't like it another `C-s` gets the next one. Continue until you're happy (you'll need an extra `C-s` to wrap around from the and of the buffer). New enough emacsen can also highlight all the matches that are visible.

As noted in the comments by  Török Gábor, this is the typical keybinding of `isearch-forward`. In the event that your bindings are different, you need to modify the prescribed procedure.

Comment: `isearch-forward` (i.e. `C-s`) also allows you to type `C-o` after the given search phrase, and then it runs `occur` what LB suggested. This way you can use their power at once.

Comment: Thanks, Török. One more thing I didn't know about emacs.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me -- `C-o` is bound to `open-line`.